# Updating Merge Field twice but its taking merge field value updated first time

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

1. Creating envelope in draft status and adding recipient while creating.
2. Using embedded view for the recipient and on visit updating recipient details like name, email, title and custom merge field.
   Performing API call in below sequence.

a. Update Recipient:
PUT

```
{
  "signers": [
    {
      "routingOrder": "1",
      "roleName": "Signer 1",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "test@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

b. Update Custom Tag 
PUT

```
{
  "titleTabs": [],
  "textTabs": [
    {
      "value": "VP, Finance Test Updated 1",
      "tabLabel": "ContactTitle",
      "tabId": "TABID",
      "recipientId": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

c. Add Custom Field 
POST

```
{
  "textCustomFields": [
    {
      "value": "**0031a00000hi8rsAAA**",
      "show": "true",
      "required": "true",
      "name": "**Contact**",
      "errorDetails": null,
      "configurationType": "salesforce"
    }
  ]
}
```

d. Send Envelope (Update Status to sent if it is in draft status)
PUT

```
{
  "status": "sent"
}
```

3. The user doesn't sign but just close the browser window.
4. Now different user visits the DocuSign embedded URL as the signer. Then following API call takes place.

a. Update Recipient:
PUT

```
{
  "signers": [
    {
      "routingOrder": "1",
      "roleName": "Signer 1",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "test@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

b. Update Custom Tag 
PUT

```
{
  "titleTabs": [],
  "textTabs": [
    {
      "value": "VP, Finance Test Updated 2",
      "tabLabel": "ContactTitle",
      "tabId": "TABID",
      "recipientId": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

c. Add Custom Field 
POST

```
{
  "textCustomFields": [
    {
      "value": "**0031a00000hixyzAAA**",
      "show": "true",
      "required": "true",
      "name": "**Contact**",
      "errorDetails": null,
      "configurationType": "salesforce"
    }
  ]
}
```

5. This user updates the merge field present in the document which is linked with Salesforce contact's title field and sign envelope. Docusign updates record which is updated in 2.c instead of final custom field I.e when user sign which is updated in 4.c
6. When I perform rest call to see the custom fields present in envelope, it shows record id updated in 4.c

Can you please let me know what would be the issue?

Comment: I've formatted your question and fixed some JSON errors in 1.a and 4.a. What endpoint are you updated in 4.b? If you're updating the custom tab endpoint and it has already been applied to the envelope, it will not impact the envelope.

Comment: Custom tag gets updated properly. I am facing issue with custom field.

Comment: Can you please update the url for your operations.

Comment: So you're intending to change the Salesforce relation of an envelope after it has been sent? URLs would help a lot here

Comment: Stackoverflow not allowing to add more than 2 url.